# Update array while maintaining a reference

Tags: javascript

Not sure if what I want is possible, but

This works:

```
pointer = arr1 = ['a','b','c'];
arr1.splice(0, 1);
console.log(pointer); // ['b','c']
```

What I would like, but does not work:

```
pointer = arr1 = ['a','b','c'];
arr1 = ['e','f'];
console.log(pointer); // desired ['e','f']
console.log(pointer); // reality ['a','b','c']
```

Is there any way around this, other than constantly re-updating the `pointer` variable each time `arr1` gets reassigned?

Comment: No, JavaScript doesn't have pointers. The only way would be if you put the Array in an Object, then updated the Object's Array. Then any reference to the Object would see the update.

Comment: That is brilliant! I will use an object and store the array inside, then save a reference to the object. That way reassignment of the property wont break the original reference. Please put this in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JavaScript doesn't have pointers. The only way would be if you put the Array in an Object, then updated the Object's Array. Then any reference to the Object would see the update.

```
var pointer = arr1 = {array:['a','b','c']};
arr1.array = ['e','f'];

console.log(arr2.array);    // ['e','f']
console.log(pointer.array); // ['e','f']
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript do not have pointers.

Suggestion given by @user2736012 in comments is a good idea ie to put Array in an Object, then updated the Object's Array. Then any reference to the Object would see the update.